# What are the base saves for a 15HD dragon with 12 monk levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, monsters, saving-throw

I am aware of numerous house-rules, such as the fractional system, which intend to overcome the shortcomings of just adding numbers on charts together. I'd like to know if such an alternative system exists anywhere in a rules-as-written Paizo publication and if so what the outcome should be.

My reading of the rules-as-written is to just add numbers from the charts.

- Dragons have "Good" saving throws, equal to ½HD+2
- Monks have "Good" saving throws, equal to ½HD+2
- Generally round down in all maths unless otherwise noted.

Dragon: \$\lfloor½(15)+2\rfloor = \lfloor7.5+2\rfloor = \lfloor9.5\rfloor = 9\$
Monk: \$\lfloor½(12)+2\rfloor = \lfloor6+2\rfloor = \lfloor8\rfloor = 8\$
Total: \$9 + 8 = 17\$

If the above is not correct, then please cite publication and page number.

I use the example of a creature with all good saves and a class with all good saves to avoid hand-wringing about already-trod topics such as the alleged absurdity of stacking multiple 1-level dips into "good" classes to cheese saves or the unfairness of multiiclassing with "bad" saves yielding a bunch of zeros.

I am aware of what the rules-as-written tag means, and that is what I want. Cheers!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an optional rule from the Unchained book makes things different. See [Fractional Base Bonuses section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this creature would have a base save bonus of +17 in each of the three saves. Your math and reasoning are correct.

Comment: if you use the fractional rule system from pathfinder unchained the total would be 15 1/2 due to only getting the +2 bonus on a good save once

Comment: @jneko Ah, decent point: in 3.5e, the official *Unearthed Arcana* version of the fractional variant left the +2 in for each class, since the idea was to make the system as similar to the non-fractional system as possible, with the only difference being rounding. The Pathfinder version of the variant goes farther. I just removed the reference to the fractional system since it wasn’t asked for and seems like it would only clutter the answer to go into those details.